# What are the features of Windows Live Movie Maker vs. Windows XP Movie Maker

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, windows-movie-maker

I am trying to figure out if its worth upgrading to Vista from XP, because I can't seem to run Windows Live Movie Maker on XP.  What are the benefits of this new movie maker software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most noticable changes is the inclusion of the Ribbon menu system.  Also it's got built in features for uploading to popular video sites (i.e. YouTube). I just downloaded the new Movie Maker yesturday and I havn't had a chance to use it yet but I've read that it has new transitions, effects, and editing capabilities as well as additional video format supports.